# Save PHP Session information

Tags: php, session

I'm suffering the next weird problem.

```
if (isset($_GET["invdata"])) {
    $_SESSION["invdata"] == "aaa";
    print_r($_SESSION);
}
```

the print_r shows me the SESSION information, but I can't see invdata information, what can be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try changing

```
$_SESSION["invdata"] == "aaa";
```

with

```
$_SESSION["invdata"] = "aaa";
```

(note the single =)

Comment: OMG, Hours of coding today, i was blinded... ridiculous mistake... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well the double equal signs are not helping!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$_SESSION["invdata"] == "aaa";
```

With

```
$_SESSION["invdata"] = "aaa";
```

You can't be setting variables with `==` now can you.